# ActionListener for a menu item using JGraphMenu

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

How can I do an ActionListener for each button in the list?  I'm using `JGraphMenu` & want to display an alert for each item.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
List<String> MenuItem = new ArrayList<String>();
MenuItem.add("Choose The XML File");
MenuItem.add("Generate the tree");
MenuItem.add("Generate the latex code");
MenuItem.add("Generate automata");
List<ActionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener();
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
listeners.add(null);
}

JGraphMenu menu = new JGraphMenu(
ConstantesStyles.NOIR,
JGraphMenu.VERTICAL, 
MenuItem, listeners
);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(menu);
panel.setSize(50, 100);
f.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
f.setSize(500, 400);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding `null`s to the `ActionListener`'s list, add listeners (in my example, the same listener, but you get the idea):

```
List<ActionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener()>;
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
    }
};
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    listeners.add(listener);
}
```